# Tkinter Entry Multiple Vaildations

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, textbox

I'm trying to validations both on key ***and*** focusout such that entry is restricted to allowable characters
and I can call a function when the user focuses out (leaving valid entry).

Is something like this possible?

```
import tkinter as tk


class Example(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    vcmd = (self.register(self.on_validate), '%S')
    vcmd2 = (self.register(self.if_valid), '%s')

    # This is the meat of the question; looking to do something like
    self.entry = tk.Entry(self, 
                          validate="key", 
                          validate2="focusout",
                          validatecommand=vcmd, 
                          validate2command=vcmd2)

    self.text = tk.Text(self, height=10, width=40)
    self.entry.pack(side="top", fill="x")
    self.text.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

    def on_validate(self, S):

        # Disallow anything but binary string
        if S == '1' or '0':
            return True
        else:
            self.bell()
            return False

      def if_valid(self, s):
          if len(s) == 3:
             self.my_function(s)
             return True
          else:
             return False

     def my_function(self, value):
        # send value somewhere
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from :https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html
Perhaps you want to use **all**?

> 'focus' Validate whenever the Entry widget gets or loses focus (see
>   Section 53, “Focus: routing keyboard input”).
>
> 'focusin' Validate whenever the widget gets focus.
>
> 'focusout' Validate whenever the widget loses focus.
>
> 'key' Validate whenever any keystroke changes the widget's contents.
>
> 'all' Validate in all the above situations.
>
> 'none' Turn off validation. This is the default option value. Note
>   that this is the string 'none', not the special Python value None.

If it was essential that you only validate `focusout` and `key`, then you could use `all` and then in your validation method you could simply call the `.get_focus()` method to see if the focus was on the box or not.

Comment: I have used 'all' and added additional logic inside the validation function to handle each d type separately. Thanks